# Web Controller HttpPost copy Request.Body missing data

Tags: c#, rest, async-await, http-post

My web controller shall receive a (large ~ 2 MB) byte stream with `[HttpPost]` as endpoint and move the data to next process step (storing).

Since there can be a lot of calls I like to copy the body data asynchronously

This is my code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostContent()
{
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  {
    Task t = source.CopyToAsync(ms);
    t.ConfigureAwait(false);
    t.ContinueWith((t1) =>
    {
      fileWriter.Save(ms);
    });
  }
  return Ok();
}
```

This is fired by one or multple REST-clients multiple times a second.

But when the callback function gets invoked, the stream in `ms` is incomplete.

When using

```
Task t = source.CopyToAsync(ms);
t.Wait();                            <---- sync it
fileWriter.Save(ms);
```

instead, it is working.

So isn't it possible have this `POST` called multiple times not until the previous body is read? And if not what is the use of this to read async or am I making a mistake in thinking?

(Sorry for not using syntactic sugar)

Thanks !

[Edit]

This is what I get when waiting. The data is completed (by ~1.8 MB)

[image]

This is what I get using callback. It is only ~266 KB

[image]

Comment: Why are you copying to a `MemoryStream` in the first place? Just use `fileWriter.Save(Request.Body);`

Comment: Actualy fileWriter does not write anything, The MemoryStream is held in a queue. This queue is going to process the incomming data.What I am interested in is why the async transfer is not working

Comment: You probably need to reset the memory stream back to start after writing into it. `ms.Position = 0` I think

Comment: I do later in `fileWriter.Save(ms)` with no effect

Comment: Then if you're not showing all the relevant code, in a [mre] then there's nothing we can really do to help you.

Comment: See my edit. There is data missing regardless of the head position of the `MemoryStream`. The code in the method which takes the Stream is too much to reproduce.